# Merging arrays into one array in same field MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a question on merging arrays into one array in same field, but they are in different objects. I hope you will understand what I wanted after looking at the code below.

```
 db.addresses.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62a72be40c7db0af0b79d721"),
        "rollingStockNumber" : "922698325786980137200129101715063039706000000",
        "addresses" : [
                "Raximova",
                "Raximova",
                "Raximova",
                "Nazarbek",
                "Oxunboboyeva",
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62a8727978c18925711d40f2"),
        "rollingStockNumber" : "922698012567076507200129101700057022060000000",
        "addresses" : [
                "Toshkent",
                "Chuqursoy",
                "Chuqursoy",
                "Chuqursoy",
                "Chuqursoy",
                "Chuqursoy",
                "Chuqursoy",
                "Toshkent",
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62a878d778c18925711d40f7"),
        "rollingStockNumber" : "922720020326980977200102111555058048630000000",
        "addresses" : [
                "Oxangaron",
                "Oxangaron",
                "Oxangaron",
                "Oxangaron",
                "Oxangaron",
                "Oxangaron",
                "Jaloir"
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I wanted to merge "addresses" arrays in one array called "allAddresses", used $group, $concat, but failed...

```
 "allAddresses" : [
                    "Raximova",
                    "Raximova",
                    "Raximova",
                    "Nazarbek",
                    "Oxunboboyeva",
                    "Toshkent",
                    "Chuqursoy",
                    "Chuqursoy",
                    "Chuqursoy",
                    "Chuqursoy",
                    "Chuqursoy",
                    "Chuqursoy",
                    "Toshkent",
                    "Oxangaron",
                    "Oxangaron",
                    "Oxangaron",
                    "Oxangaron",
                    "Oxangaron",
                    "Oxangaron",
                    "Jaloir"
            ]
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `null` and add `addresses` into `addresses` array. It returns a nested array.
2. `$project` - With `$reduce` to flatten nested array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      addresses: {
        $push: "$addresses"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      allAddresses: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$addresses",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rzRaDGE4SUY)

Comment: Thanks, it works. By the way, is it same syntax for Node.js? Can I use like "const allAddresses = Address.aggregate(..........." ?!

Comment: Yes, you can use the above pipeline in Node.JS. `const response = Address.aggregate(/* Pipeline */); const allAddresses = response[0]["allAddresses];`.

Comment: Bro, it shows undefined...(   How can solve??

Answer (score 0):

Easier approach:

1. Unwind the existing array
2. Append all the unwind objects

Here is the code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
       path: "$addresses",
       preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allAddresses: {
        "$push": "$addresses"
      }
    }
  }
])
```